# Printing Spec. sheet along with sales order

Tags: acumatica

Item Spec. and instructions are attached to items as a pdf and while printing sales order, I have to attach the spec. pdf and print. The pdf may have more than one page. How to add the pdf file and print dynamically with sales order printing?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to store the item spec and instructions in the item maintenance screen.  This information could be an image file for each item.  Next, you will create a sub-report.  It will contain a picture-box, whose source is the database and the image file associated to the inventory item which stores the image.  The subreport contains the input parameter  InventoryID, in order to link it to each inventory item in your sales report.  Finally, embed the sub-report into the details section of your main report, so that each spec & instructions are printed in the main report.

If you don't want the sub-report option, you could add your item spec and instructions in the Description box, in the item maintenance screen.  It is a rich-text box control, so some formatting is retained.  Then you can bind that field inside your report.